# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0 when using lists

Tags: java, arrays

```
class Solution {
    public List<Boolean> kidsWithCandies(int[] candies, int extraCandies) {

    Arrays.sort(candies);
        int max =candies[candies.length-1];
        List <Boolean> res = new ArrayList<Boolean>(candies.length);
        for(int i =0;i<candies.length;i++){
            if(candies[i]+extraCandies > max){
                res.set(i, true);
            }
           else{
               res.set(i,false);
            }
        }
    return res;
    }            
 }
```

I am getting an error of java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0. Can anyone suggest me where i am going wrong.

Comment: you are trying to access the first element of an empty list/array. First check whether or not there are elements to access

Comment: You cannot use the `set(int index, E element)` method of List to set Elements at indexes that don't yet exist. Lists don't work like that, you can't insert an element at index 0 in an empty list with that method. And your List is empty when you create it. You add new elements with the add method and use the set method to replace elements.

Comment: That `List` is empty, so instead of setting the elements on `index i`, just add them to the list.

Comment: You've made the assumption that the parameter you pass to `new ArrayList` is the size of the list, as it would be with `new Boolean[size]`, but it isn't, it's the number of items you can add to the list before it resizes itself internally. The list is created empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set elements of an empty `List` like that, you need to actually add the elements to populate an empty list. Here, you seem to be checking if each-value in the input array is within a threshold; use that as the value to add. And I would calculate the threshold once. Like,

```
public List<Boolean> kidsWithCandies(int[] candies, int extraCandies) {
    Arrays.sort(candies);
    int max = candies[candies.length - 1] - extraCandies;
    List<Boolean> res = new ArrayList<>(candies.length);
    for (int v : candies) {
        res.add(v > max);
    }
    return res;
}
```